# Force SSL for http requests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ssl, https

I'm working on a platform built with Ruby(v2.1.2) on Rails(v4.1.6) and we're trying to enforce SSL. How do I go about doing this?

So far, I have `force_ssl`

```
# application_controller.rb

force_ssl if: :ssl_configured?

def ssl_configured?
  return false if params[:controller] == 'high_voltage/pages'
  (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?) ? false : true
end
```

Which seems to work because when I try to do http://www.somecoolsite.com, it then automatically becomes https://www.somecolesite.com.

However, if I try to submit a JSON post request to the API portion of our platform, and the URL is `http://`, the post request is somehow returning the results of a get request instead. But when I change the URL to `https://`, the post request works as expected. How would I go about fixing this so that if a client accidentally submits their request as `http://`, it is rewritten to `https://`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using `config.force_ssl = true` in your production environment config? This is far more all-encompassing, but can lead to other issues as well.